# React hook not updating value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a simple hook where I pass an user to my function, and it sets this user in the hook to be used in other components.

This is how my hook is set:

```
export const useChat = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null)

  function setChatWithUser(user: User) {
    setUser(user)
  }

  return { user, setChatWithUser }
}
```

I use the setChatWithUser to send the user to my hook, and then I set the user and send it to another component:

```
export const OnlineUsers = () => {
  const { documents, error } = useCollection("users", null)
  const { setChatWithUser } = useChat()

  const handleClick = (user: User) => {
    setChatWithUser(user)
  }

  return (
    <C.Container>
      <h2>All Users</h2>
      {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
      {documents &&
        documents.map(user => {
          return (
            <div key={user.id} className="user-list-item" onClick={() => handleClick(user)}>
              {user.online && <span className="online-user"></span>}
              <span>{user.displayName}</span>
              <Avatar src={user.photoURL} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
    </C.Container>
  )
}
```

```
export const Chat = () => {
  const { user } = useChat()

  console.log(user)

  return (
    <C.Container>
      <C.Header>
      <Avatar src={user?.photoURL} />
      </C.Header>
      <C.Content></C.Content>
      <C.MessageInput></C.MessageInput>
    </C.Container>
  )
}
```

But apparently it runs only once in the Chat component, and it shows a null value for the user variable. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not calling `setChatWithUser(...)` anywhere in `<Chat/>`, which would actually update the user. By default it'll be the initial `user` value, which is null, until you update it

Comment: updated my question with the other component

Comment: Ok so just how every `useState` React hook has its own distinct state value, every `useChat` hook has its own internal state value. It's not shared across all usages of that hook. If you want **one** chat instance shared throughout the app, you'll have to use that hook in one place and pass down the `user` and `setChatWithUser` values for that specific hook via props or context or the like